# Nginx location doesnt workd

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have a Django app running with Nginx and Gunicorn on **mysite.com**. I would like it to be accessible only under **mysite.com/myapp**. This is my nginx configuration:

```
 server {
        listen 80;
        server_name server_domain_or_IP;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
        root /home/sammy/myprojectdir;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

When I change ***location /*** to ***location /myapp/***, I get "Not found error". Nginx error log doesn't seems to have anything. What could be the issue?

Comment: Do you read my comment under your previous question?

Comment: When you change `location /` to `location /myapp/`, your app homepage becomes `http://yourdomain/myapp/`. All routes should be changed from `/some/path/` to `/myapp/some/path/`.

Comment: Try add trailing `:/` at proxy_pass directive, like `proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock:/;` so it will rewrite to correct socket path - `/`  instead of `/myapp/,`

Comment: @mgsxman I tried adding ':/', and it indeed works, but only for mysite.com/myapp page. It looks like I need to add the prefix to all of my urls, like Ivan Shatsky suggested.

Comment: @mgsxman That would not solve the problem of links generated by app itself, all of them need to be prefixed too.

Comment: @IvanShatsky You are right, thank you again.